# To show if $a_{n}\downarrow 0$;  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{n}<+\infty \Leftrightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Delta a_{n}\log n<+\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that if $a_{n}\downarrow 0$ then $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{n}<+\infty \Leftrightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Delta a_{n}\log n<+\infty.$

I am stuck to prove this result. Please help me out.

Comment: What is $\Delta a_n\log n$?

Comment: $\Delta a_{n} \log n= (a_{n}-a_{n+1}) \log n$

Comment: $\displaystyle \sum_{k=m}^{n}a_{k}b_{k}=\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}\Delta a_{k}B_{k}+a_{n}B_{n}-a_{m}.B_{m-1}$, where $B_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}b_{k}$.So i have to use this formula but how?

Comment: Take $b_k=1/k$, then $B_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n 1/k\approx \log n$

Comment: $$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{a_{k}}{k}=a_{n}B_{n}+\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\Delta a_{k}B_{k},\tag{1}$$  where  $\displaystyle \log n< B_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}<1+\log n$                                Let $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{n}<+\infty.$$    From $(1)$, we have, $$|a_{n}B_{n}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\Delta a_{k}B_{k}|\leq M$$ Which further implies that $$|\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\Delta a_{k}B_{k}|\leq M$$ $$\therefore \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\Delta a_{k}B_{k}<+\infty.$$ $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\Delta a_{n}\log n<\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\Delta a_{n}B_{n}<+\infty.$$ I am proving only one part. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: @Norbert Can we prove this result without using Abel summation formula?

Comment: I don't know, Abel transform is not a sledgehammer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every $N\geqslant1$,
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{a_n}n=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\Delta a_n\cdot H_{\min\{n,N\}}\quad\text{with}\quad H_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac1k\sim\log n,
$$
hence
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}\Delta a_n\cdot H_n\leqslant\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{a_n}n\leqslant\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\Delta a_n\cdot H_n.
$$
Using the bounds $H_n\geqslant\log n$ for $n\geqslant1$ and $H_n\leqslant2\log n$ for $n\geqslant2$, one gets
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}\Delta a_n\cdot \log n\leqslant\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\frac{a_n}n\leqslant\Delta a_1+2\sum\limits_{n=2}^{+\infty}\Delta a_n\cdot \log n.
$$